# Error encountered while installing erlang-solutions on linux-mint 18 Sarah

Tags: package, erlang, elixir, linux-mint, dpkg

I am trying to install elixir for the first time as mentioned in here https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like. But I am getting this error even after I removed the previous downloaded erlang-solutions package.

```
 ~ $ wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
--2019-11-16 13:18:53--  https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
Resolving packages.erlang-solutions.com (packages.erlang-solutions.com)... 13.224.106.98, 13.224.106.9, 13.224.106.63, ...
Connecting to packages.erlang-solutions.com (packages.erlang-solutions.com)|13.224.106.98|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6288 (6.1K)
Saving to: ‘erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb.3’

erlang-solutions_2. 100%[===================>]   6.14K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-11-16 13:18:54 (660 MB/s) - ‘erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb.3’ saved [6288/6288]

 ~ $ sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
(Reading database ... 211574 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-solutions (2.0) over (2.0) ...
Setting up erlang-solutions (2.0) ...
Can not detect version codename.
dpkg: error processing package erlang-solutions (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 erlang-solutions
```

Comment: Looks like ES does not know about _mint_. Try to temporarily change your `/etc/lsb-release` to the original distro, [tag:mint] is based on, or, better, ask this question where _mint_ users are the majority. Maybe superuser.stackexchange.com is also a good place.

Comment: change the mint to ubuntu, it is an debian based distribution fully compatible with ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Debian 9.11 section.
The problem is in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/erlang-solutions.postinst` you can change `set -e` to `set -x` to debug and see why it returns a 1, but I have downloaded the latest version of https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html and it worked correctly for me

Answer (score 1):

On Debian-based systems you may have to explictly install Erlang to get all the needed packages.

```
$ sudo apt install erlang
```

[Checkout this PR](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_guides/commit/a0118871392d1e6ea54b0b2541d84fd577270baa)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the postinstall script mentioned by [oscii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814035/12757261): `/var/lib/dpkg/info/erlang-solutions.postinst` converts the distribution listed in `/etc/issue` into a codename, which is in turn used to configure a debian repository. Unfortunately, it only looks for Debian, Ubuntu and Raspbian tags and versions.

The easiest solution is to temporarily replace your `/etc/issue` file with the one of the debian/ubuntu your distribution is based on.

In my case (SparkyLinux 6, based on Debian bullseye), that codename wasn't actually included in the list, so I quickly added the codename "bullseye" to the postinstall script for my specific situation.

Running `sudo apt-get install` again, completed the installation.

Comment: "The easiest solution is to temporarily replace your /etc/issue file with the one of the debian/ubuntu your distribution is based on. ... so I quickly added the codename "bullseye" to the postinstall script for my specific situation."


Hi @jurriaan could you be more specific here? What exactly should that line say if you've got debian bullseye?

Comment: using the version downloaded with

`wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb`

The maximum Debian version I have found on the postinst script was 9; It worked ok for me by just putting:

`Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l`

on the /etc/issue file.

Obs.: the \n and \l are NOT escaped; they are written on that file exactly like this.
Obs.2: after this line, there is an empty line; I don't know its purpose, but I suggest you keep it there